# Creating new payment method for Bigcommerce

Tags: payment, bigcommerce

I would like to know if this is possible to add new payment method for Bigcommerce. I tried to contact their support without any luck. If anyone is familiar with bigcommerce and know if this is possible, i would appreciate any advice.

I already read their API docs and didn't found anything useful - only method to obtain list of available payment methods.

I already tried to signup for their partner. Without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've done this before for a couple stores to allow clients to process payments through their own processor. The way we achieved this, is essentially through the following high-level steps:

1. Allow payments by Check (or similar offline method). We are going to replace this with the custom processor.
2. You'll notice that if you attempt to checkout via Check, that BigCommerce automatically creates the order for you, but sets the order status to `Awaiting Payment`. Upon submission the user is automatically sent to a 'Thank You' Order Confirmation page that contains both the Order ID and some payment instructions (such as where to send the check to).
3. Here's the trick -- Modify this 'Order Thank You' page to prompt the user for her or his credit card information. A simple HTML form will suffice here, performing the actual request via JavaScript.
4. Once you have the user's credit card data, you can then POST it to your own external server, where you would connect to and send data to whichever processor you are using. Additionally, you should make sure to send the Order ID to this program, so that you can connect to the BigCommerce API to load billing information, and then subsequently adjust the order status to either approved or declined depending on the response from your processor. Finally, you should send back some sort of response to the client to inform of the result of the charge attempt.

That's pretty much it in a nutshell. The way you integrate with the payment processor (step 4) is unique to whichever processor you are using. I hope this makes sense.

Although opinion based, I'm a huge fan of serverless technologies, and would suggest looking into AWS Lambda + AWS API Gateway. The benefit here is that you don't need to worry about creating an infrastructure or the associated concerns of security and scale. Rather, AWS Lambda allows you to simply upload your software, and allows it to be executed via an HTTP request to some defined endpoint set through the API Gateway. Lambda will scale automatically for you, and you don't need to worry about system level security concerns - only security at the application level. It's truly a set and forget setup, and a bleeding edge technology. Not to mention dirt cheap!

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a new payment method is unsupported and requires hacky workarounds since we implement payment gateways via the core app. You can do this on blueprint by using an offline payment method and then using the API to update payment statuses, etc. I'd recommend using [ActiveMerchant](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant) if you do wish to go down this path.