# Do we have DigitalRiver payment method supported in BigCommerce?

Tags: payment, bigcommerce, bigcommerce-checkout-sdk

I want to add a new payment method in BigCommerce for Digital River.

- The API's don't allow.
- I have seen the workaround mentioned in : [Creating new payment method for Bigcommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907628/creating-new-payment-method-for-bigcommerce)

But that's just a hack, and we need something build in, don't want to write the DR wrapped in whole.

- I looked at the SDK : https://github.com/bigcommerce/checkout-sdk-js/tree/master/src/payment/strategies/digitalriver
  where DR is added couple of weeks ago, is this something going to be supported sooner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that this is not currently supported via apis in the docs. As creating a new payment integration is not as straight-forward as other integrations, such as shipping or tax for example, which use the rest apis in the BigCommerce dev docs.

This process requires a partnership with BigCommerce, in addition to being a large time & resource investment. I do have good news though -- BigCommerce is currently working with this provider to build this integration! :)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Heather.
Is there any forum / github issue or api doc that i can track? to understand when it gets released ?

Comment: One the integration has been completed, you should notice the option on your store. However, the announcement will likely be made in a Town Hall event.   https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/BigCommerce-Town-Halls